# Complement operator in C

Tags: c, twos-complement, tilde

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  int i = 3;
  printf("%d", ~i);
}
```

The output is 2. 3 is 0000 0011. Tilde changes all the bit to their opposite. So how is the answer even 2?
As I have read from other posts. 2's complement is `(~i)+1` which makes `~` 1's complement operator. Even if it is so how is 2 a possible output?

Comment: `void main()` is wrong. `The output is 2` I cannot get this output. What compiler are you using? What compiler options are you using? What operating system are you using?

Comment: The output here is `-4`.

Comment: Where do you get such output?

Comment: What output? the result of `echo $?`, perhaps?

Comment: I am really sorry I checked again, the data type was int. Is using int changing things up? Well I am using gcc Mingw with windows 10. I just checked out  with char and the answer is -4. So 1111 1100 is -4 in 2'complent. I don't understand 2's compliment well enough. and int being 4 bytes should make the answer 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100. is it 2 in 2's complement ?

Comment: @AnaghBasak, it's the same, you could make an 8 bit representation 1111 1100 or even a 64 bit representation 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100, the converted value is the same -4.

Comment: I don't know what was wrong with my system after trying for several rounds the answer is -4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt the answer it's 2. It should be **-4**, which *is* the decimal representation of 11111100.

<kbd>[Online Run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TiHwBAYBOt4jOSfA)</kbd>, which outputs:

```
-4
```

Indeed [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is calculated by inverting the digits and adding one. So -4 + 1 = -3, as @WeatherVane commented.

---

PS: Unrelated to your question, but the `main` method typically returns an `int`, not `void`. Read more in [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Reference: [Section 5.1.2.2.1 of the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> It shall be defined with a **return type of `int`** and with no
> parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though
> any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they
> are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> <sup>10)</sup> Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as `char **argv`, and so on.

as @JérômeRichard commented.

Comment: I hit 'Enter' before I had finished so I deleted it. The two's complement of `3` is surely `-3`? Invert and add `1`.

Comment: Absolutely @WeatherVane, thank you so much for the comment and the upvote, answer updated! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. the main function should be `int main(void)`
2. The answer is not 2 only -4 https://godbolt.org/z/b1GGv8

Comment: I have a question that is with normal functions the programmer gets to choose the return type. What's different with main(). Each program I ran main() with a void return type never produced an issue? What actually goes wrong when  I change the return type to void?

Comment: Because standard says that. The question is like what will happen if I ignore the red light? Or stop sign? I did it many times before and nothing happened. So those lights and signs are not needed. I will **never** stop on the red lights.

Comment: Why does the standard say that what is the problem with void main? If I don't follow traffic signal  I might end up in an accident. So according to your logic I might crash somewhere so where exactly? That is my question. IT's risky but what is the risk. Initilization is needed so that I don't end up dealing with garbage. wh

Comment: @AnaghBasak look at [Section 5.1.2.2.1 of the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). The rational is that the host environment (ie. OS) need to know if the program finished correctly and without an `int`-compatible type as a return type (eg. `void`), the "status returned to the host environment is unspecified" (ie. undefined behavior on most OS).

Comment: @AnaghBasak when you write a method in your program, e.g. `int read_file(char filename[16]);`, then you want, as the caller of this method to know if everything went well (because failures can happen, e.g. file could not be found). By checking the return value of the method you can know if everything went well or not, it's a mechanism for the method to signal you about its successful execution or not, and let the caller (you) decide how to handle an unexpected failure. So now imagine I write a C program for a micro-mechanism which is used in a more complex system. When the system calls the ...

Comment: ...micro-mechanism, it wants to know if everything went as expected, so that it can handle any potential error. If the C program's main method would return `void`, then how would the calling-system know about the execution of its subsystem (the micro-mechanism)? It cannot, that's why `main()` returns `int`, in order to communicate to its caller a successful (or not) execution. That was an example that helped me understand the signature when I was in university, hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for  such a gullible explanation.